# Initialize a a struct's vector with random values based on the structs RNG-member in the constructor

Tags: rust, initialization

I have a struct that has its own RNG (random number generator) as a member and a vector with random values. Can I initialize this struct's RNG with a random seed and then directly after fill the vector with random numbers based on that seed?

```
use rand::{rngs::SmallRng, SeedableRng};

struct Example {
    values: Vec<f64>,
    rng: SmallRng,
}

impl Example {
    pub fn new(random_seed: Option<u64>) -> Self {
        Task {
            rng: SmallRng::seed_from_u64(random_seed.unwrap_or_default()),
            values: vec![ ??? rng.gen() ??? ; 10], // this does not work.
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround, or an idiomatic way for doing such things?

Comment: What is stopping you from allocating `rng` in `new`s stack frame, doing the necessary computations, then moving `rng` into the struct to construct?

Comment: oh right, that does work! I always thought about move to be kind of bad in rust, because i always associated it with compiler errors. But here it is actually a perfect fit. Then before I initialize the struct I create these variables outside it and leave them (move) in the struct. I'll update my question with a solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you're satisfied with your answer/comment, please consider posting it as an answer, rather rhan just editing the original post. It helps filtering through posts faster.

Answer (score 0):

As L. Riemer pointed out I can initialize the member variables first and then 'move' them in the struct while it is initialized:

```
impl Example {
    pub fn new(
        random_seed: Option<u64>,
    ) -> Self {
        let mut rng = SmallRng::seed_from_u64(random_seed.unwrap_or_default());
        let values = vec![rng.gen_range(-1.0..1.0); 10];
        Task {
            rng: rng,
            values: values,
        }
    }
}
```